# Bad certificate error with SSL

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, keytool, pkcs#12

I have a webstart application where I want to do client authentication while connecting to the server. I have created pkcs12 certificate which I install using certmgr.exe and it works fine. 
I want to do for every client that uses the application. How should I do this? If I distribute the certificate

I get a bad_certificate error. I know there isn't a problem with the certifcate because  it would work if you install the certificate using the browser.

I had created the public key using

`keytool -export -alias myKey -keystore abc.p12" -storetype PKCS12 -storepass mypassword -rfc -file abc.cer`

then I imported this file into my server's keystore for mutual authentication using:

keytool -import -v -file abc.cer -keystore C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\tomcat.keystore" -storepass mypassword

after this, if I install abc.p12 certificate in certmgr, it works fine.

To be able to do it from Java, I needed a truststore. I created a truststore where I import the public key using

`>keytool -import -keystore client-truststore.jks -file abc.cer`

If I try to access the server using

`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=abc.p12 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypassword`

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing. Please let me know what you think.

What should I be doing? Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should have imported it into your server's trust store, not its keystore.

Comment: It is the TrustStorefile for tomcat where I import the cert.  keytool -import -v -file abc.cer -keystore C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\tomcat.keystore" -storepass mypassword

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the cert to your certs file, in the JDK is the cacerts file. After do that you have to view the cert is living on the file, and you will have do that on every client.

The thing about the trust store is that you create your own JKS file.